# How to find out why system keeps freezing?

Tags: 18.04, freeze, amd-ryzen

I have recently installed Ubuntu 18.04.2 on my Laptop and am experiencing regular freezing, where all windows and actions freeze (can't type, press buttons, etc.) but I can (sometimes) still move my mouse pointer (but even then, it can't click anything).

Once it freezes the only thing I can do is hold the power button down and restart it. The freezing seems completely random, and has happened when doing multiple different tasks.

You can see my lshw output here https://privatebin.net/?2f77830db7565fdd#W0cP/pE0ZfEvOTYW2QDSzDZR0GfU9dDcvUz8f6CKwTc=

I have tried looking through syslog, kern.log and also looked in /var/crash (which contained nothing) and could not see anything that stood out to me (although i'm new to this, so I may be missing something obvious).

The only thing I can think of is that it has a Ryzen CPU, but even then it seems like a lot of Ryzen issues were fixed with Ubuntu 18.

I previously had the latest Kubuntu installed and that worked fine (it did occasional freeze, but it was much, much less frequently).

Whats my next step? Is there anything I can do to either find out why its crashing, or to stop it crashing?

Answer (score 0):

I have also spent a lot of time trying to find the reason for random freezes on my Ryzen5 system. No guarantee that this works for you, since there can be a lot of different reasons, but what seemed to have fixed it for me (fingers crossed) was to disable "Automatic C-State Management" in the BIOS. You'd have to look for yourself where it is and how it is named exactly in your BIOS. It's worth a try.

Comment: Don't have anything like that in my BIOS. Any other recommendations?

Comment: Not really - as I said, it can be anything. I would maybe start with checking from another PC if the machine is still reachable via network when it freezes, or doing a memory check with memtest86. Then you could start trying another distribution from a USB stick and wait if that freezes as well, in that case it's probably linked to hardware. I guess you eliminated all the obvious reasons like faulty hard drive or overheating already.

Answer (score 0):

On my Ryzen 5, I faced the same problem. Although later, I figured out that this is not the Ryzen related issue.

I hope this will work for you.
I've faced the same problem that Ubuntu 18.04 freezes from time to time. Ubuntu 18.04 completely froze while I was coding, then sometime later the same happened when I watched a movie it was a problem that was not related to the GPU and had random occurrence. I've found this solution after hours of searching. 
Just run this command and restart your computer.

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04
```

After restarting, verify that the 5.0.0.x generic was installed:

```
uname -a
```

That'll work fine.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04.4 came out recently. If one uses this ISO to create the installation Live USB, it will come with kernel 5.3. If one uses (or has already used before) the command above, it will also switch to kernel 5.3 as Ubuntu automatically updates from 18.04.3 to 18.04.4.